# Load in `.vimrc` themes and plugins from custom locations

Tags: linux, vim

My home folder is loaded dynamically from a a network. I want to keep some configuration files
like for vim, in a different location.

I want to do this because I can have the same user on different machines, but each computer can have different settings, in some cases missing for example plugins.

I have a symbolic link from `.vimrc` in home folder to a file in another location.

In `.vimrc` I have added settings for plugins, themes. I don't want to create symlinks also pentru `.vim`, .`viminfo` from home to other location.

How can I set in `.vimrc` the paths for them and plugins ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this answer work? https://superuser.com/questions/413942/use-another-users-vimrc-and-vim

```
$> env VIMINIT=/home/user/.vimrc VIMRUNTIME=/home/user/.vim/ vim

$> VIMINIT='let $MYVIMRC = expand('\''~user'\'') . '\''/.vimrc'\''|source $MYVIMRC' vim -c 'set runtimepath=~user/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,$VIM/vimfiles,$VIMRUNTIME,$VIM/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~user/.vim/after'
```